# How to call the 'callee' function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a simple JQuery slidein-slideout divs where each div slides in, waits for lets say 1 sec, then slides out so that the next div slides in.

All is working fine but my problem is that I can't make the div wait for a certain time before sliding up. Please check the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/47vzx/.

I tried to do the following:

```
if(i<datalength)$('#paneldata').slideDown(2000,i==bdatalength?null:setTimeout(_callee,1000));
```

but was not able to make it work
Thank you

Comment: Is this what you wanted ? http://jsfiddle.net/47vzx/2/ . i just increased the delay in slideup().

Comment: No, what I am intending to do is to to make the div waits some time before sliding up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Using : `arguments.callee` instead, inside the function.

```
var _callee = arguments.callee;

if (i < datalength) $('#paneldata').slideDown(2000, function () {

        if (i != bdatalength) _callee();
});
```

Your [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47vzx/3/)

Comment: I am already using this in another way **_callee = function(){** and i am using **_callee** inside the function which I find it to be the same as calling arguments.callee inside the function. Am I wrong? My problem is how to use that arguments.callee function in setTimeout ?

Comment: Yes you are correct. But `setTimeout` cannot have the conditional statement, it only accepts functions. You could pass an anonymous function to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try add a [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) before the slideUp call

```
i=-1; 
$data = $('#panel .data');
datalength = $data.length-1;
bdatalength = datalength-1; 
$panel = $('#panel').fadeIn(1000,_callee = function(){
    $('#paneldata').delay(i < 0 ? 0 : 2000).slideUp(2000,function(){
        $(this).html( $($data[++i]).html() )});
    if(i<datalength){
        $('#paneldata').slideDown(2000,i==bdatalength?null:_callee);
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Jqrx8/)